# best method for numerical integration of power-pade approximant

Tags: numerical-integration

I have to evaluate integrals which have the following form $$\mu=\int_0^\infty r^k \Psi(r) dr \tag{1}$$ where $$\Psi=exp (-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac {c_kr^k}{(1+g\,r)^{N-3}}) \tag{2}$$ Trying `NIntegrate` to evaluate $\mu$ returns many errors like this

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand E^(-(r/(1+d r)^5)-(16.5 r^2)/(1+d
>   r)^5-(72. r^3)/(1+d r)^5-(250.55 r^4)/(1+d r)^5-(822.401 r^5)/(1+d
>   r)^5-(2753. r^6)/(1+d r)^5-(9677.98 r^7)/(1+d r)^5) has evaluated to
>   non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with
>   boundaries {{[Infinity],0.}}.

What I tried:

```
\[Psi][d_][r_] := 
  Exp[-Sum[(cc[[k]] r^k)/(1 + d*r)^(NN - 3), {k, 1, NN - 1}]];

\[Mu][d_][k_] := NIntegrate[r^k \[Psi][d][r], {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
```

and then

```
f[d_][k_] := 
  k (k - 1) \[Mu][d][k - 1] + 2 z \[Mu][d][k] + 
   2 energy \[Mu][d][k + 1] - 2 \[Alpha] \[Mu][d][k + 2] - 
   2 \[Beta] \[Mu][d][k + 3];
\[CapitalDelta][d_] := Sum[f[d][k]^2, {k, 1, NN}];
newd = FindMinimum[\[CapitalDelta][d], {d, 1.3}];
```

where you can use

```
cc={1, 16.5, 72., 250.55, 822.401, 2753., 9677.98};
NN = 8;
energy = 40
\[Alpha] = 0;
\[Beta] = 100;
d = 1.5;
z=1;
```

for numerical test.

For this reason, the final results are so in-consequent. So I think that I should modify the integration method, but there are many methods for `NIntegrate` in Mathematica and I really don't know how should I chose the best for my case, Any idea?

Comment: How did you try `NIntegrate`? Please show us the specific code sample.

Comment: @xzczd I added the code.

Comment: What's the value of `d`?

Comment: @xzczd it was added

Comment: Now what's the value of `k` in `\[Mu]`? BTW I don't think it's a good idea to use `k` both in `\[Psi]` and `\[Mu]` for different meaning.

Comment: @xzczd its value is specified in $Psi$ definition. Also I use `f[d_][k_] := 
  k (k - 1) \[Mu][d][k - 1] + 2 z \[Mu][d][k] + 
   2 energy \[Mu][d][k + 1] - 2 \[Alpha] \[Mu][d][k + 2] - 
   2 \[Beta] \[Mu][d][k + 3];
\[CapitalDelta][d_] := Sum[f[d][k]^2, {k, 1, NN}];` after this and k again is specified. The `k`'s are the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. `k` in `\[Psi]` is the index for summation, while `k` in `\[Mu]` is a `r^k` term outside of `\[Psi]`, how can they be the same? Are you sure your $\LaTeX$ formulas are correct?

Comment: I mean they have the same values in the formula, namely they are represented by the same notation

Comment: Do you mean you need to calculate `\[Mu]` for $k=1,2,…,N-1$?

Comment: @xzczd  yeah in fact in the next commands

Comment: I cannot reproduce the mentioned warning with `\[Mu][d][#] & /@ Range[NN - 1]`. Please show the complete code sample that generates the warning.

Comment: @xzczd  I added the rest of code

Comment: (-1) Value of `z` is missing. Please make sure your code reproduces the mentioned problem before posting here. Will retract my downvote after the sample is properly given.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\[Mu][d_?NumericQ][k_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[r^k \[Psi][d][r], {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
```

Now you can evaluate the function

```
Table[{k, \[Mu][d][k]}, {k, 0, 5}]       
(*{{0, 0.20112}, {1, 0.0246749}, {2, 0.00447831}, {3, 0.000980942},{4,0.000241742}, {5, 0.0000647909}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However after that, when I try to run `f[d_][k_] := 
  k (k - 1) \[Mu][d][k - 1] + 2 z \[Mu][d][k] + 
   2 energy \[Mu][d][k + 1] - 2 \[Alpha] \[Mu][d][k + 2] - 
   2 \[Beta] \[Mu][d][k + 3];
\[CapitalDelta][d_] := Sum[f[d][k]^2, {k, 1, NN}];
newd = FindMinimum[\[CapitalDelta][d], {d, 1.3}];` (where energy=26.5, alpha=0 and beta=100), the errors again emerge : `"NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 \
recursive bisections in r near {r} = {0.828623396219416`}."`

Comment: Perhaps `\[CapitalDelta][d_?NumericQ] :=...` together with `NMinimize` might help.

Comment: @Wisdom There is a parameter `z` inside `f[d][k]`

Comment: z is simply 1 as I have specified in the question

Comment: @Wisdom Notice $g$ (`d` in the code) or $r$ probably needs constraint, because there's a $1+gr$ in the denominator.